# Retrieve Firebase Data saved with push()

Tags: android, firebase

I have a Firebase database.When im saving data i used the `push()` to generate auto increment key.

now my db like this

```
    recipe{
     Categories{
     -KJxZi0jbE1sY5cCFgqf{
        name: "Sri Lankan"
        }
      }
    }
```

When im retrieving data i got this error

`W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -KJxz53rLIc4rZPVjK48 found on class com.kosala.uyamu2.Data_Category`

This my `Data_Category` Bean

```
public class Data_Category {

    String name;

    public Data_Category() {}
    public Data_Category(String name) {
        this.name = name;}
    public String getName() {
        return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;}}
```

This is where i retrieving data

```
mDatabase.child("recipe").child("Categories").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Data_Category data = dataSnapshot.getValue(Data_Category.class);
                        Log.d("name", data.getName());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Can any one help me here.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) 
                     Data_Category category = data.getValue(Data_Category.class);
       }
 }
```